# Insert query for chained one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql

I've struggled with this query for two days.
I have three tables. the relation among them is one to many.

Here is more details

Table 1:

```
TABLE Table1 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
              filename VARCHAR(255))
```

Table two:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table1(id), 
                     Question VARCHAR(255))
```

Table three:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Table2(id), 
                     Answer TEXT NULL, 
                     Probability FLOAT NULL)
```

The relation between Table 1 and table 2 is one to many.

the relation between table 2 and table 3 is one to many.

if I want to insert the values (Answer, Probability) into table 3, what is the correct way to do that.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: ID should be independent in every table and not FKs to another table. In table2 and 3 create a new field to be the FK pointing to the referenced table id

Comment: @P.Salmon: Primary keys which are also foreign keys are a common way to model weak entities. That's not per se something bad. What's useless though is that the `id` in the referencing tables is declared as `AUTO_INCREMENT`. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: INSERT INTO Table3 (table2Id, Answer, Probability) VALUES ( ...,...,...);

Comment: *if I want to insert the values (Answer, Probability) into table 3, what is the correct way to do that.* Noway. Your source data does not contain the info what question/filename this data must be related to.

Comment: In addition to each table's own primary key field (`id`), you should create an independent field that holds the foreign key, which contains the name of the target table as prefix (`table2Id` or table2_id for ex.) Then, as described by @Aston, you can insert the data ascending the table hierarchy, starting with the records of `Table1` up to those of `table3`. During the insertion process, you must grab the foreign keys and fill them in the relevant foreign key fields of the dependent records.

Comment: @MikeF. Thanks Mike! I tried as you and aston mentioned. Do I need to describe the field is a foreign key? because when I tried this:  'CREATE TABLE Table2 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY (Table1id) REFERENCES Table1(id), Question VARCHAR(255)); ' it is said the 'Table1id' doesn't exist  in table1

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. That what I will try to do. you mean I should have field in table2 and table 3 both of them point to table 1 as FK. Right?

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for this information. I think I can use filename as PK as well. it is work. both Id or filename can be a PK

Comment: @kaloon: Like I said, a primary key being also a foreign key isn't wrong, if you want to enforce that every referencing entity can only exist when a corresponding referenced entity exists. So if that's the case in your model, don't worry about it.

Comment: @stickybit When I tried to create a FK for table1 id in table 2 enforce me to use id. I need field in table 2 reference table 1. I just modify my tables like Aston and Mike mentioned. I got error. see here what i tried https://extendsclass.com/mysql/f331c43

Comment: I'm sorry I find why I got an error. I forget to create the filed first.